# How to combine variable argument definitions and function with receiver in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I am able to define a function that accepts a variable number of arguments (see: `testVariableArguments` below) and I can define a function with a specified receiver (see: `testFunctionWithReceiver` below). I am wondering if there is a way to combine both of these concepts?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    testVariableArguments { a: Int -> println(a) }
    testVariableArguments { a: Int, b: Int -> println("$a, $b") }
    testVariableArguments { a: Int, b: Int, c: Int -> println("$a, $b, $c") }
    testVariableArguments { a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int -> println("$a, $b, $c, $d") }

    testFunctionWithReceiver {
        doSomething()
        doAnotherThing()
    }
}

fun <R, T : Function<R>> testVariableArguments(function: T) {
    val method = function::class
            .java
            .declaredMethods
            // May need to do something else here to get the
            // correct method in case the return type is 
            // expected to be Object, but for my case it 
            // would never be Object
            .first { m -> m.name == "invoke" && m.returnType != Object::class.java }


    val args = method
            .parameterTypes
            // Mapping to Int here for demonstration, in real
            // situations would use the parameter types to
            // create the correct value
            .withIndex()
            .map { i -> i.index }
            // Not really needed, but would be if I were 
            // using multiple types and not just Int
            .map { i -> i as Any }
            .toTypedArray()

    method.invoke(function, *args)
}

fun <R> testFunctionWithReceiver(function: MyInterface.() -> R) {
    val myObject = object : MyInterface {
        override fun doSomething() {
            println("doing something")
        }

        override fun doAnotherThing() {
            println("doing another thing")
        }
    }
    function(myObject)
}

interface MyInterface {
    fun doSomething()
    fun doAnotherThing()
}
```

EDIT:

I have found a way to combine these two features, but it is a bit messy at the call site, so if there is a better approach I would be interested.

What I did was add the following operator function to `MyInterface`

```
operator fun <R, T : Function<R>> T.unaryPlus() {
    testVariableArgumentDefinition(this)
}
```

Then when I call `testFunctionWithReceiver` I do the following:

```
testFunctionWithReceiver {
    +{ a: Int, b: Int ->
        println("$a, $b")
        doSomething()
        doAnotherThing()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter requirements to the closure called with receiver by adding:

```
MyInterface.(P) -> R
```

Replacing your creation of test parameters with a fixed one, this is what it might look like:

```
fun <R, P> testVariableArgumentsWithReceiver(param: P, function: MyInterface.(P) -> R) {
    function.invoke(myObject, param)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    testVariableArgumentsWithReceiver(17) { a: Int ->
        println("$a")
        doSomething()
        doAnotherThing()
    }
}
```

Of course, you're not as flexible here as you need to pass a single value of type P (which could be an array). You can extend it to `MyInterface.(P,Q)` but not arbitrary signatures per se.

What you truly want is a signature like this:

```
fun <R, T: Function<R>> someName(function: MyInterface.T)
```

or

```
fun <R, T: FunctionWithReceiver<MyInterface, R>> someName(function: T)
```

To my knowledge, neither can currently be expressed:

- Only function-type *literals* seem to be allowed as part of extension types; `MyInterface.T` is not valid code.
- There doesn't seem to be a first-class type for functions with receiver; we can't declare `FunctionWithReceiver`.

This may be worthwhile to bring up on [discuss.kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/)